# Sharepoint API Fetching 3 times? Instead of 1

Tags: sharepoint-online, query, api

I have been facing this issue whereby my sharepoint api is fetching more than once. The function is only being called once BUT it fetches more than once..? Which causes some issue for the displays.

```
    function fetchData(url, type, siteExist) {
        console.log("Fetching Data: "+ url ); // ONLY RUNS ONCE. 
        let timestamp = new Date().getTime();
        let apiUrl = url + "&timestamp=" + timestamp;
        
        fetch(apiUrl, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
             if (type === 'eFile'){
                eFileResponse = [];
                if (data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults != null){
                    let totalPages = Math.ceil(data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.TotalRowsIncludingDuplicates / 10);
                    console.log("Total pages: "+ totalPages);
                    if(totalPages > 0){
                        totalResults = data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.TotalRows;
processResultsAndRenderCards(data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results, type);
                    }
                } 
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
    }
```

Comment: the problem isn't with this code, it's that this code is being called multiple times. Let's see your component.

Comment: If there’s any other code that could be triggering the `fetchData` function while it’s waiting for a response, that could cause multiple fetches.